# Why you must login to ask a question in physics.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

Why you must login to ask a question in http://physics.stackexchange.com
while other sites are free and open to everyone?
Link: [How does it work](http://stackexchange.com/about)

> ...**you can ask or answer questions without even bothering of register**...
>   Why Phys.SE is out of scope of Stackexchange!?

Comment: IIRC there are other sites on the network like this, too, it depends on the amount of spam/nonsense that gets posted here.

Comment: Interesting, StackOverflow itself also has this restriction, but most of the other sites do not.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is mistaken. Physics Stack Exchange should be just like every other stack exchange in basic mechanics.

Comment: Looks like [networkengineering.se] doesn't require login for asking questions. Maybe a beta site thing?

Comment: @Manishearth Physics shouldn't require login unless you asked for this to be enabled. Except for short bursts of spam this typically only happens one much larger sites (e.g. Ask Ubuntu).

Comment: @Mad Is that something we can check on, or do we have to ask for help? (I couldn't find it in the moderator tools.)

Comment: @dmckee You'll have to ask someone from the comm team if and why this is enabled, moderators can't see any of this.

Answer (score 1):

I also observe this behaviour. Visiting the site on incognito chrome and trying to ask a question prompts me directly for a log in. From a random smattering of sites from the bottom of this page:

- TeX, Web Applications, Webmasters, Game Development (and presumably most sites) show visitors straight to the Ask a Question page.
- Stack Overflow, Programmers, and possibly others, directly prompt you for a log in.
- ServerFault (and others?) sends users to [a pretty nice How to Ask page](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask/advice), including a prominent search bar, that won't let you proceed to the question page until you promise to "keep these tips in mind when asking".

I'm not sure why the log-in prompt is enabled for this site. **It should be disabled** as we do not really have much of a spam problem. At most, we should have the ServerFault version, but I should think even that is unnecessary.

Comment: Actually, we did use to have a bit of a (physics) spam problem, but most users weren't noticing that since we usually dealt with it.